# Selecting all the row combinations from a matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix consisting of 10 rows ,
I would like to make a combination between these row using R such as:

```
M= matrix(c(
     1,2,3,4,
     5,6,7,3,
     5,5,4,8,
     5,2,7,8,
     4,8,7,8,
     2,6,7,9,
     5,6,7,4,
     5,6,7,2,
     5,6,7,3,
     5,6,7,0),nrow=10, byrow=TRUE)
```

---

**First step**

combination (3 row ) from ( 10 row ).

This means that we have other matrices (resulting from matrix `M`) their number 120- matrix(3*4)

**Second step**

combination (6 row ) from ( 10 row )
This means that we have other matrices (we also resulting from matrix M) their number 210-matrix(6*4)

Comment: Hi! Welcome, what have you tried so far? People will be more likely to answer if you show what you tried. Also you should post an example of the desired output.

Comment: You could try `lapply(combn(10,3,simplify=FALSE),function(x) M[x,])`.

Comment: This would be much more clear if you show the output you are after.

Comment: Hi nicola .. The Newton Ruphson for row results  , for the following equations: a0 + xb + yc ^ 2 + zf ^ 3 = 0 , a1+xb^2+yc+zf^3=0 , a2+xb+yc+logz(f)=0

Answer (score 0):

You can split `matrix` with `apply` to `list` of rows than use `combn` function as below:

```
M <- structure(c(1, 5, 5, 5, 4, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 6, 5, 2, 8, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 3, 7, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 3, 8, 8, 8, 9, 4, 2, 
3, 0), .Dim = c(10L, 4L))
x <- apply(M, 1, list)
# combinations for three rows
cmbs3 <- combn(x, 3) 
ncol(cmbs3)
# 120
cmbs3[, 2]
# second combination
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3 4
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1] 5 6 7 3
# 
# 
# [[3]]
# [[3]][[1]]
# [1] 5 2 7 8

# combinations for six rows
cmbs6 <- combn(x, 6)
ncol(cmbs6)
# 210
```

EDIT:
Or use elgant solution provided by nicola - subsetting by row index generated by `combn` (I like it much more :):

`lapply(combn(10, 3, simplify = FALSE), function(x) M[x, ])`

Output:

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    5    6    7    3
[3,]    5    5    4    8

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    5    6    7    3
[3,]    5    2    7    8
...
[[119]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    5    6    7    4
[2,]    5    6    7    3
[3,]    5    6    7    0

[[120]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    5    6    7    2
[2,]    5    6    7    3
[3,]    5    6    7    0
```